# Dirac delta multiple integral bounds

Tags: integration, dirac-delta, quantum-field-theory

I'm struggling to understand the bounds on integration region after performing integral over Delta function.

**Correct** result from book:
$$
\int_0^1dz \int_0^1 dy \int_0^1 dx \delta(x+y+z-1) = \int_0^1dz \int_0^{1-z}dy
$$

I do not understand why second integral has bound $0<y<1-z$ ?

My attempt (**incorrect** somewhere):

Since $$\int_a^b \delta(x-x_0)= 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } a<x_0<b\\
    0,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Doing first x integral gives

$$\int_0^1 dx \delta(x+y+z-1) = 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } 0<1-z-y<1\\
    0,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Which would imply the bounds on y to be: $-z<y<1-z$

Comment: You have evaluated the innermost integral, after that you need to evaluate
$$\int_0^1 [-z < y < 1 - z] \, dy.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown

$$\int_0^1dz \int_0^1 dy \int_0^1 dx \delta(x+y+z-1) = \int_0^1dz \int_0^1dy\chi_z(y)$$

Where $$\chi_z(y) = \begin{cases}1,&-z < y < 1-z\\0, &y\le -z \text{ or } 1-z \le y\end{cases}$$

But what you've overlooked is that you are only integrating $y$ from $0$ to $1$. It doesn't matter that $\chi_z(y) = 1$ for values of $y < 0$, because the integral does not extend to that region. When restricted to $[0,1]$, the function is 
$$\chi_z(y)\mid_{[0,1]} = \begin{cases}1,& 0 \le y < 1-z\\0, &1-z \le y\le 0\end{cases}$$